# Using Grid-Like Data in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, grid

I recently wrote code for a project euler problem, and by the time I had worked around every bug I ran into my code was pretty convoluted and no longer pretty and efficient. I had to manually manipulate my data far too much for my liking. I cannot find a straight forward answer elsewhere and would like a more graceful solution.

I'm not even sure this is possible in **C**, so keep that in mind.

The problem requires analyzing a grid of data that is in pain text.
The grid is as follows...

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

The idea is to find the largest possible product of four adjacent numbers (vertical, horizontal, or diagonal).

In the end my solution involved manually inputting this into a two-dimensional int array and manually changing all 08's or 09's to  8's and  9's to avoid the octal number problem.

Like so...
    `int str[20][20] = {{ 8, 02, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 00, 75, 04, 05, 07, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91,  8},{49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 04, 56, 62, 00},{81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 03, 49, 13, 36, 65},{52, 70, 95, 23, 04, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 01, 32, 56, 71, 37, 02, 36, 91},{22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80},{24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 03, 45, 02, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50},{32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70},{67, 26, 20, 68, 02, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63,  8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21},{24, 55, 58, 05, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72},{21, 36, 23,  9, 75, 00, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 00, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95},{78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 03, 80, 04, 62, 16, 14,  9, 53, 56, 92},{16, 39, 05, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 00, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57},{86, 56, 00, 48, 35, 71, 89, 07, 05, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58},{19, 80, 81, 68, 05, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 04, 89, 55, 40},{04, 52,  8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 07, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66},{88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 03, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69},{04, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18,  8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36},{20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 04, 36, 16},{20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 01, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 05, 54},{01, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 01, 89, 19, 67, 48}};`

This is not only tedious but it seems in efficient as well. Is there a way in c to take this data from the plain text grid, besides using a char string? And if not what would be a more elegant way to take this data?

I am self taught so I apologize for any glaring holes in what I know.

Comment: I feel really bad that you did this all manually, providing a generous answer (5 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in c to take this data from the plain text grid, besides using a char string? And if not what would be a more elegant way to take this data?

The approach to take is: save the data as a file (say `input.txt`) and pipe it to my program and read all of the entries through `stdin`. It would look like the following:

```
int rows = 20;
int cols = 20;
int arr[ rows ][ cols ] = { 0 };
int crow = 0;
int ccol = 0;
int num;

// Iterates until EOF is sent through stdin.
while ( scanf( "%d", &num ) != EOF ) {
  // Determines whether we have filled all of the columns, if so 
  // reset the current column to 0 and increase the current row 
  // by 1.
  if ( ccol >= 20 ) {
    ccol = 0;
    crow++;
  }

  // Mutate arr at position ( ( col * crow ) + ccol ) to have the 
  // value num.
  arr[ crow ][ ccol ] = num;
}
```

... this would be inside a function in your driver file (possibly `main`). What this is doing is, reading each number one at a time then populating the array and stopping when `EOF` is sent (end of file). See documentation for `scanf` ([here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)) for further details.

You would then run your program as follows to pipe the input file to your program:

```
./program.out < input.txt
```

**Remark:**

- I am not using a dynamic array or blocks of memory from the memory pool. If you plan to receive an arbitrarily large file then I suggest implementing a dynamic array using the memory pool (as the stack is rather small in comparison to the memory pool).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "piping the input file to my program"? Would I write that into my code somewhere? And what is the EOF in the while loop?

Comment: @Charles, included an explanation of what is going on.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know I could read outside files from a simple c program like this.